# Why was my resource recommendation question closed for needing more focus?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons

[Books on general properties of matter and fluids](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/609612/books-on-general-properties-of-matter-and-fluids).                                Can anyone please tell why this was closed and down voted? The topic comes under properties of bulk matter, which includes theory of elasticity and fluid flow, pressure, statics, and surface tension. I am looking for a good physics book for self study which has good theory and good problems to test the concepts. I don't know how can I make the question more focused to reopen it. Generally in one book all of the topics are given, so I asked about everything together.

Comment: I have even edited the question and made it about Fluid only and also wrote about the sub topics i desire then also it's closed what should i do? please any suggestions.

Comment: You didn’t edit the title, which still refers to “general properties of matter”.